# I can't get my changes to user to persist in user table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-identity

When I make changes to a user field in the usermanager, I can't get those changes to persist in the user table by updating the userstore.

I have tried userstore.updateasync, userstore.savechanges, etc.

```
Dim dbcontext As New ApplicationDbContext
Dim store1 As New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(dbcontext)
Dim manager1 = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(store1)
Dim currentUser = manager1.FindById(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId())

SubscriptionState = "Inactive"
currentUser.SubscriptStatus = SubscriptionState
manager1.UpdateAsync(currentUser)
store1.Context.SaveChangesAsync()
```

I want to be able to change the subscription status of a user and have those changes remain in the user table.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with the code is that UpdateAsync is an asynchronous operation, so the thread will just continue onto the next line of code before UpdateAsync finishes. This means the SaveChangesAsync function  most likely finishes before the UpdateAsync function is finished. You can add an await operator before UpdateAsync to make sure it finished before SaveChangesAsync.

Comment: What would the syntax for that be?  I tried:Await manager1.UpdateAsync(currentUser) but that does not work.